# Is a node.js app running on express.js hosted in Azure using IIS?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, iis, server

I'm working on a app that is hosted in Azure.
The app is a web-app based on node.js/express.js.
**Is it running on/in a IIS server since it is hosted in Azure?**

My app does not use the iisnode package. But i wonder if it is inherently running on IIS since it is hosted in Azure?

Also: As i understand at the moment, IIS-express and express.js is two completely different environments for hosting web-servers.....?

Comment: If I recall correctly, azure will autmatically create a config for you node app for iisnode. This means that your node runs behind an IIS and the IIS will be forwarding requests to your express/node app. Perhaps someone from Azure will have more precise answer. Regard IIS-express and express.js: Correct, those are completely separate things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just according to your description, it seems that you were talking about hosting a node App based on express.js to Azure WebApp for Windows.

Yes for hosting Node.js app in IIS on Azure WebApp for Windows, you need to use iisnode (a native IIS module) to host node.js applications with the `web.config` file in IIS on Windows. For more details, you can refer to the wiki page [`iisnode wiki`](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/wiki) of GitHub repo [`Azure/iisnode`](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode) to know what iisnode is, and to know how to host it with a `web.config` file in IIS via the other wiki page [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) of GitHub repo [`projectkudu/kudu`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu).

However, No for Azure WebApp for Windows, because you also can use IIS as a reverse proxy server to handle a Node app via the default port `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` specified by Azure WebApp like the blog [`Running java jar file to serve web requests on Azure App Service Web Apps`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/12/28/running-java-jar-file-to-serve-web-requests-on-azure-app-service-web-apps/) for Java said. But generally, it's not a recommended way.

Meanwhile, No for hosting Node app on other Azure services, such as Azure WebApp for Liunx, Azure VM, or Azure Container services, these services based on Linux do not require IIS, so the iisnode module also be not absolute required.